# Non readable - YANG

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-restconf

There is a way to define non readable data in yang?

```
module system{
   leaf name{
      type string;
   }
   leaf password{
      type string;
   }
}
```

So in this case 'password' is the non readable data.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to make the data "unreadable", you can use `binary` built-in type, which enables you to set an arbitrary blob of bytes (base64 encoded) as the value for a leaf. Encrypted bytes included.

```
leaf password {
  type binary;
  default "cGFzc3dvcmQ="; // <-- plain text "password"
}
```